# How do I use .then() after a new Promise is resolved, before returning the whole function as resolved

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

```
promo()
    .then((e) => console.log("finished everything"))
    .catch((e) => console.log("failed everything"))
    .finally((e) => console.log("done", e));

function promo() {
    console.log("awaiting promise");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout((e) => {
            console.log("done with first promise");
            resolve("done");
        }, 2000);
    }).then((e) => {
        console.log("starting second promise");

        new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout((e) => {
                console.log("done with second promise");
                resolve("done2");
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
}
```

how do I make it so promo() doesn't finish until the second .then() is finished? right now it returns it as soon as the first promise ends, and the .then() is triggered after finally();

here is the output:

```
awaiting promise
done with first promise
starting second promise
finished everything 
done 
done with second promise
```

but what I expect is:

```
awaiting promise
done with first promise
starting second promise
done with second promise
finished everything 
done
```

Comment: Why do you expect that?

Comment: because it returns a promise with .then() after it and also that's what i want it to do and i also i barely understand how promises work

Comment: You need to `return` the promise that is in the then() callback, when it detects a promise being returned it waits for that one to finish before continuing on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a return:

```
}).then((e) => {
  console.log("starting second promise");
//VVVVVV
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout((e) => {
      console.log("done with second promise");
      resolve("done2");
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

Any time you call `.then` on a promise, you create a new promise. If you return a promise in the `.then` callback, then your new promise will resolve with whatever that returned promise resolves to. If instead you return a non-promise value, then the new promise resolves to that value, with no additional delay. Since you're implicitly returning `undefined`, your new promise resolves to undefined as soon as the first promise is done.